# Problema de reemplazar números en un archivo

Tags: java, archivo

Saludos tengo una duda que me viene acosando desde hace rato. Se trata de lógica. Quiero recorrer un archivo con varios números (uno en cada renglón) leyendo cada número y reemplazándolo en su línea por el siguiente por medio de una reescritura. Ej.: viendo el listado de aquí abajo, que el 153 pase a ser 156, que el 156 pase a ser 163, que el 163 pase a ser 171, etc. He estudiado extensivamente el problema con distintos prototipos sin lograr solucionarlo. Yo mismo le he nombrado al problema "El Problema del Bucle Maravilla".

```
153
156
163
171
181
189
195
202
```

Acá va uno de mis extraños prototipos:

Tengan en cuenta que br es un BufferedReader y bw es un Buffered Writer.
`rugosidad` es una variable que inicialicé antes y representa la cantidad de números en la lista del archivo. `data` es un String.

```
data = br.readLine();
for (int i = 0; i < rugosidad - 1; i++) {
                System.out.print("Pasando número(" + i + ")... ");
                data = /*Integer.toString(i);*/br.readLine();
                System.out.print("Data: " + data + ". ");
                System.out.print("Escribir(" + i + ") " + data + ". ");
                //if(data != null) {
                bw.write(data/*Integer.toString(i)*/);
                //} else {System.out.println("\n\nError, data es null.\n\n");}
                bw.newLine();
                bw.flush();
                System.out.println("Número pasado.");
            }
```

Comment: ¿Tienes algún código con lo que has intentado?

Comment: Si, dame un momento y lo pasaré editando la pregunta.

Comment: o sea el unico problema es que no los graba uno por renglon?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**PROBLEMA**

Se desea recorrer un archivo de texto que contiene números (cifras), y reemplazar cada cifra con el valor de la linea siguiente. Al final el archivo tendrá 1 linea menos.

**SOLUCIÓN**

La siguiente solución usa Java 7 o superior.

Para recorrer un archivo y luego reemplazar los datos en el mismo usaremos las siguientes Clases:

1. `Files` - librería `java.nio.file`.
2. `Paths` - librería `java.nio.file`.
3. `BufferedWriter` - librería `java.io`.
4. `FileWriter` - librería `java.io`.
5. `IOException` librería `java.io`.
6. `List` librería `java.utils`.

Se creará una estructura `List` para almacenar los datos del archivo, usaremos el método `ReadAllLines()` de la Clase `Files` para almacenar todas las lineas de nuestro archivo en la lista.

Luego se inicializará el Buffer de escritura y se recorrerá la Lista para extraer cada linea y volcarla en nuestro Buffer, asegurándonos que se escribe según lo solicitado en el enunciado.

Por último se cerrará el Buffer para escribir los cambios al disco.

El programa quedaría de la siguiente manera:

```
import java.nio.file.Files;
import java.nio.file.Paths;
import java.io.BufferedWriter;
import java.io.FileWriter;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.util.List;

public class bucleMaravilla {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        // Declaramos FileWriter y BufferedWriter
        FileWriter fw = null;
        BufferedWriter bw = null;

        try {
            // Leemos el archivo y almacenamos el contenido en una estructura List
            List<String> lines = Files.readAllLines(Paths.get("./numeros.txt")); // si se usa Windows sustituir la ruta adecuadamente


            try {
                // Instanciamos FileWriter y BufferedWriter
                // la opcion 'false' de nuestro FileWriter indica que sobreescribiremos el archivo
                fw = new FileWriter("./numeros.txt",false); // si se usa Windows sustituir la ruta adecuadamente
                bw = new BufferedWriter(fw);

                // Recorremos el List
                for (String line : lines) {
                    // se descarta la primera linea (indexOf(line)=0)
                    if(lines.indexOf(line) > 0) {
                        // escribimos en el Buffer e insertamos una nueva linea
                        System.out.println("Leyendo linea " + lines.indexOf(line) + " y escribiendo en linea " + (lines.indexOf(line) - 1) + ": " + line);
                        bw.write(line);
                        bw.newLine();
                    }
                }

                // cerramos el buffer y escribimos el archivo
                bw.close();
            } catch (IOException ew) {
                ew.printStackTrace();
            }
        } catch (IOException er) {
            er.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
}
```

Si el archivo `numeros.txt` contiene la siguiente data:

```
153
156
163
171
181
189
195
202
```

El resultado será:

```
156
163
171
181
189
195
202
```

**Nota**

El programa fue testeado en ambiente Linux, por favor corregir la ruta del archivo para trabajar en ambiente Windows.

La documentación de Java sobre el método `newLine()` hace la acotación siguiente:

[BufferedWriter - Java](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/io/BufferedWriter.html)

> **newLine():** Writes a line separator. The line separator string is defined by the system property line.separator, and is not necessarily a single newline ('\n') character.

Espero que este ejemplo te sirva de ayuda para resolver tu problema.